# Chatterbot/spacy: Can't find model 'en'

Tags: python, chatterbot

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
chat = ChatBot('cctmx')
while True:
    peticion = input('>>>: ')
    respuesta = chat.get_response(peticion)
    print("Bot: " + respuesta)
```

this error comes out when run

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Luisl\Desktop\bot.py", line 2, in <module>
    chat = ChatBot('cctmx')
  File "C:\Users\Luisl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\chatterbot.py", line 28, in __init__
    self.storage = utils.initialize_class(storage_adapter, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Luisl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\utils.py", line 33, in initialize_class
    return Class(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Luisl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\storage\sql_storage.py", line 20, in __init__
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Luisl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\storage\storage_adapter.py", line 23, in __init__
    'tagger_language', languages.ENG
  File "C:\Users\Luisl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\tagging.py", line 26, in __init__
    self.nlp = spacy.load(self.language.ISO_639_1.lower())
  File "C:\Users\Luisl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\spacy\__init__.py", line 30, in load
    return util.load_model(name, **overrides)
  File "C:\Users\Luisl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py", line 175, in load_model
    raise IOError(Errors.E050.format(name=name))
OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52677634/pycharm-cant-find-spacy-model-en